# How to automatically import daily log files into SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server

I have a folder where my log files are getting dumped 4-6 times a day. Each log file name begins with 'Order...' e.g. 'Orders20180216-011402-756.txt'. I am able to up import this file through the Import Wizard.

How can I automatically upload the new log files onto the SQL Server? I don't mind these being uploaded just once a day, and I plan to move the '.txt' file to archive folder. So the logic that I though was "Any Order*.txt file in the folder -> upload it to the database and then move the file to archive folder.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SQL Server Native Client                                    11.0
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      14.0.17177.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    14.0.806.134
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.15063.0
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.15063.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                            6.3.15063
```

Comment: Use SSIS and schedule the job through the job agent.

Comment: This is overly broad, there are many solution for this. Use an ETL process (like SSIS as @dfundako has recommended) and then schedule the task (for example using the SQL Agent). I've voted to close this due to being too broad.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available for such kind of task:

- schedule a sql server agent job with bulk insert into db from your
  log files
- create sql server integration services package

You can easily find the details and step-by-step guides, for example here:

- [bulk insert](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/)
- [ssis package](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)